# OptimisticLockingFailureException: Batch update returned unexpected row count

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data

I have a simple Parent Child onetomany unidirectional relationship in place in my Spring Web MVC application. I have 2 RESTful api's: POST & PUT.

Parent Entity:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"children", "id"})
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PARENT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Set<Child> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Child Entity:

```
@Entity
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = {"id"})
public class Child {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/parent")
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    private ServiceImpl serviceImpl;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Parent> post(@RequestBody final Parent parent) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Parent>(serviceImpl.create(parent), HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @PutMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Parent> put(@RequestBody final Parent parent) {
        return new ResponseEntity<Parent>(serviceImpl.update(parent), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Service Layer:

```
@Service
public class ServiceImpl implements inter {
    @Autowired
    ParentRepository repository;

    public Parent create(Parent parent) {
        return repository.save(parent);
    }

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Parent findById(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id).orElseThrow(IllegalArgumentException::new);
    }

    @Transactional
    public Parent update(Parent toUpdate) {
        Parent retrieved = this.findById(toUpdate.getId());

        retrieved.getChildren().retainAll(toUpdate.getChildren());
        retrieved.getChildren().addAll(toUpdate.getChildren());

        return repository.save(retrieved);
    }
}
```

I have a single Repository for the Parent. 
I create the Parent and children together as part of the POST api

I need to update the Parent and Children via PUT. 
However when I try to replace one or more children of an already created Parent I get error:

```
{"timestamp":"2019-05-27T20:21:53.451+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","message":"Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1","path":"/parent"}
```

The issue occurs only when executing a simple JMETER perf test with multiple threads.

If I change the CascadeType to MERGE on parent side of relationship then the update works but the persistence of new entity will then fail via Post api.

Comment: Optimistic locking is there to prevent one row being updated by multiple transactions. are you trying to update the same record multiple times via Jmeter ?